# Not able to Associate tests to work item in Azure devops pipeline tests(Junit report)

Tags: azure-devops, project-management

I am trying to link work items (features) with tests (JUNIT report test)in pipeline but not able to search workitem(feature) in the Associate search items , it is showing 50 suggestions only.

[image]

please suggest an option to link features to tests(Junit) under publish test section in pipeline

Answer (score 1):

The feature items cannot be searched because the list shows only work items belonging to the **Requirements category**. This is stated in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/requirements-traceability?view=azure-devops#quality-traceability).

The following image shows the Agile process backlog work item hierarchy.  **Backlog** work item types correspond to the **Requirements category**. Tasks correspond to the Task category.

[image]

For details ,please refer to this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/configure-customize?view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process#work-item-types-and-portfolio-backlogs).